# Snowflake GRANT usage on ALL SCHEMAS owned by a certain ROLE

Tags: roles, privileges, snowflake-schema

In my Snowflake database, I have a reporting ROLE requesting access to a subset of SCHEMAS owned by a subset of schema OWNERS.  This is a valid request as I can see it reduces the schema clutter in their query interface.

Is it possible in Snowflake to grant privileges on ALL schemas owned by a certain role (Ex: abc_role) to another role (Ex: xyz_role)?

I see in Snowflake we can grant privileges on ALL schemas in the entire database but not restrict by the schema owner.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to construct the commands yourself, there is no WHERE option in a grant statement.

Just run

```
show schemas;
```

and then construct your grant statements with

```
select — construct statement
from table(result_scan(last_query_id())) 
where “owner” = value;
```